# High Fidelity bluetooth playback is super quiet after sudo get-apt upgrade, volume is fine on HSP/HFP?

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I just ran sudo apt-get upgrade and A2DP volume is super quiet even on max settings. Changing sound to HSP/HFP works as expected. Changing back to A2DP causes sound to virtually be mute even on max volume. Any idea how to fix this or what might be going on?

Answer (score 2):

Found some article that mentioned that this has been happening to a few people after an update. To solve the issue unpair your headset (forget the device) and set it up as a new one. It works fine for me now.